# ¿Cómo cambiar el nombre de un archivo de un input file antes de enviarlo al servidor?

Tags: jquery, archivo, entrada

Estoy enviando el formulario mediante ajax pero por razones cómodas me gustaría cambiar el nombre del archivo cargado al input file antes de enviarlo al servidor. Se puede?

```js
document.getElementById('image1').onchange = function () {
  document.getElementById('image1').files[0].name = "hola.png";
document.getElementById('fichero').innerHTML = document.getElementById('image1').files[0].name;
}
```

```css
.inputfile {
 width: 0.1px;
 height: 0.1px;
 opacity: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
}
.fileUpload {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
}
.fileUpload input.upload {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

```html
<input id="image1" type="file" class="inputfile hidden-xs hidden-md" value="image1" name="image1" required />
<label id="fichero" for="image1" class="my-btn btn-danger"><center>Archivo 1</center></label><br>
```

Comment: Hola, sería bueno que muestres el código actual para que se más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: ¿Cuál código? hahaha Cómo escribo un código que no sé cuál es? Puedo poner un input file y cómo obtengo el nombre del archivo pero no creo que venga al caso, pero bueno, pondré código.

Comment: No creo, por el hecho de que JS no tiene acceso al sistema de archivos y no puede sobreescribir el nombre de este antes de ser enviado

Comment: Y si lo que quiero hacer es enviar ese archivo pero con otro nombre? O sea, no busco realmente cambiarle el nombre al archivo, sino enviarlo con otro nombre

Comment: Solo por curiosidad ¿Por que quieres cambiarle el nombre antes de enviarlo? ¿Cual sería la diferencia en recibir el archivo y guardarlo con otro nombre?

Comment: $("#image1").val("ficheronuevo")